# Upload OBB expansion file to Google Play draft artifact using API

Tags: android, node.js, http, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to upload an main OBB expansion file to the google play store using the Google play API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/). I am currently successfully uploading the correct APK file using the edits.apks.upload functionality described here (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks/upload).

When the file is finally uploaded to the store, it ends up in the **Draft Artifacts** section under Release management/Artifact Library: [Artifact Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu4yp.png)

Unfortunately, when I try to upload the expansion file to this using the edits.expansionfiles.upload HTTP request, the following error is returned: { The following APK version codes could not be found: 480 }. This is confusing as I can see that the APK is in draft artifacts, but it doesn't seem to be listed in the APKs available to be modified.

Does anyone have any suggestion for how I might upload an OBB to a draft artifact file on the Google Play Store? Can I only upload OBBs to APKs being used in a release track?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current version of the Google Publisher API. It has been reported to the right people at Google, but a fix could take a while.

At the moment you cannot add OBBs to draft artifacts using the API. Sorry about that.