# How do you upload an expansion file to a Draft Apk using Google Play Developer API Client Library for Java?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, gradle-kotlin-dsl, google-play-developer-api

My current workflow is I publish my apks (4 splits by abi) to alpha in draft. This works fine because I am using Gradle Play Publisher.

The next step is I upload the expansion file, this is a custom gradle task.

I start an edit with an authenticated AndroidPublisher

```
val editId=publisher.edits().insert(packageName, null).execute().id
```

For my first apkVariant I upload the expansion file

```
publisher.edits().expansionfiles()
                .upload(
                  packageName,
                  editId,
                  apkVariantOutput.versionCodeOverride,
                  "main",
                  FileContent("application/octet-stream",myFile)
                ).execute()
```

and for all subsequent variants I reference the new expansion file

```
publisher.edits().expansionfiles().update(
            packageName,
            editId,
            apkVariantOutput.versionCodeOverride,
            "main",
            ExpansionFile().apply {
              referencesVersion = apkVariants[0].versionCodeOverride
            }
          ).execute()
```

and finally commit this edit

```
publisher.edits().commit(packageName, editId).execute()
```

example output from some prints:

```
{
  "expiryTimeSeconds" : "1573666146",
  "id" : "04893130212727174754"
}
setting expansion for 6193171
{
  "fileSize" : "590199"
}
{
  "referencesVersion" : 6193171
}
{
  "referencesVersion" : 6193171
}
{
  "referencesVersion" : 6193171
}
{
  "expiryTimeSeconds" : "1573666146",
  "id" : "04893130212727174754"
}
```

But the expansion files never show up on the Play console even though the task completes without error.

I hope I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about this API because I can't make sense of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my entire app upload process with Play Developer API.

You can't upload expansion files to draft, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546291/upload-obb-expansion-file-to-google-play-draft-artifact-using-api) is still relevant. I can't find the google issue it refers to but a year later it is evidently still the case.